# Html5 video tag is not working in ios when video is from database

Tags: ios, html, video, xmlhttprequest, blob

I have a hybrid mobile app using cordova for both ios and android.
I have uploaded the video files in db as blob data. They are fetched through rest service call nd attached to src tag though httpservletresponse. The videos are not playing in ios devices where playing in android app.

Where as same files stored in a downloadable location and given in src is working fine in ios. But when fetched from the db ia npt working. Same case image files are also fetched as blob and given to img src are working fine in ios. I dont understand the issue with ios video tag.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, there is no way to know what’s wrong. However it’s very likely that your server is not properly handling http range requests.